# Add margin to a CustomView in onLayout at initialization

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-framelayout

I have a custom view which extends FrameLayout:

```
    public SlidingDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public SlidingDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        //get the attributes specified in attrs.xml using the name we included
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.SlidingLayer, 0, 0);

        init = true;
    }
```

I want to add some margin to layout in the customView:

```
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

        if(init) { 
             init = false;

             MarginLayoutParams margins = MarginLayoutParams.class.cast(getLayoutParams());
             final View parent = (View) getParent();
             params.bottomMargin = mOffsetDistance - getHeight();
                    params.topMargin = parent.getHeight()  - mOffsetDistance ;
             setLayoutParams(margins);
        }
    }
```

These margins will never apply.
Can anyone explain me the solution?

Comment: Anything special about `MarginLayoutParams`? BTW, what are those huge arbitrary margins?

Comment: I used set/getLayoutParams as well and same problem. I edited the question with correct value of margins. They were just a sample.

Comment: Just a blind guess, might it be due to first constructor being called?